# .htccess 403 redirect - same IP, different devices, only one passes

Tags: .htaccess

I've set up a 403 redirect for all visitors but mine IP and a client's. This is how it looks:

```
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/a/website/with?some=parameters
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
Allow from xx..xxx.xx.xx
```

Why does my PC, where I have setup and tested the redirect, pass, while my phone, which shares the same public IP, gets redirected?

That's it basically. Thanks!

Comment: Visit any whatismyip website from both your PC and phone to see if they are using the same IP?

Comment: That's what I did. Like I wrote, my PC and phone share the same public IPv4. I could only imagine that Apache is, even if not wanted, differentiating between the devices by their IPv6...

Answer (score 0):

So, yes. It was IPv6. Disabled it from my router and all working good again, from all devices.